# Equation for making an oval based on r=cos(th)

Tags: polar-coordinates

I have a polar graph (on paper) with a curve similar to 7.8*cos(theta). Plotting the data estimate from a nice big print-out of the graph gives a fairly close fit, but I seems that the circle needs to made into an oval to fit better. In other words it looks like a scale factor in the "y direction" (if you'll forgive me, I know it's a polar plot.)

http://ibin.co/2V7RxQNKbqbO

```
deg rad     f(r)    Real Data
0   0       7.8000  7.8
10  0.174   7.6815  7.7
20  0.349   7.3296  7.4
30  0.523   6.7550  6.9
40  0.698   5.9751  6.2
50  0.872   5.0137  5.3
60  1.047   3.9000  4.2
70  1.221   2.6678  3
```

(Beyond 70 deg a different curve applies in my problem domain so I'm not too worried about that part of the curve)

Is there another form of equation that I can use to modify r=7.8cos(th) to stretch the curve? The purpose is to use an equation to calculate the values at intermediate points, and to avoid a potentially complex lookup system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You stretch the plot vertically by a scale factor $\lambda\gtrsim1$.

Your equation was

$$\rho=r\cos(\theta),$$ and in Cartesian coordinates

$$x=r\cos^2(\theta),\\
y=r\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta)).$$

It is now

$$x=r\cos^2(\theta),\\
y=\lambda r\cos(\theta)\sin(\theta),$$

which is no more simple in polar coordinates, as

$$\rho'=r\cos(\theta)\sqrt{\cos^2(\theta)+\lambda^2\sin^2(\theta)},\\
\tan(\theta')=\lambda\tan(\theta).$$

Eliminating $\theta$, this gives this little monster:

$$\rho'=r\cos\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(\theta')}\lambda\right)\right)\sqrt{\cos^2\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(\theta')}\lambda\right)\right)+\lambda^2\sin^2\left(\arctan\left(\frac{\tan(\theta')}\lambda\right)\right)}.$$

You'd probably better stick to Cartesian coordinates with the ellipse

$$\left(\frac{x-r}{r}\right)^2+\left(\frac y{\lambda r}\right)^2=1.$$

Comment: That is some monster alright. I may simply transform to Cartesian, though I guess if the monster can be translated into code and tested properly it would do fine! Thanks Yves!

Comment: @djnz0feh: absolutely. But then one may wonder what is the relevance of using polar coordinates at all.

Comment: The goal is still to have a function in terms of theta (it is a wind direction) even if it has to be transformed along the way.

Comment: I see. The simplest is $\theta'\to\theta\to\rho'$ then.

Comment: OK. One more thing (you'll have to forgive me  - it's a long time since I was in university) $\theta\prime$ is the $\theta$, subject to checking which quadrant it should be in, no? Is $\rho\prime$ then the mangnitude but again subject to which quadrant and hence which direction?

Comment: @djnz0feh: if I am right, your curve is in quadrants I and IV for $-\pi<\theta<\pi$. Then using the tangent/arctangent will cause no problem.